# Alternative for api RSAPublicKeyImpl

Tags: java-8

I would like to know is there any alternative for below api with same parameters format from java 8

```
public RSAPublicKeyImpl(BigInteger var1, BigInteger var2)
```

currently it is depreciated & throwing sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import java.security.PublicKey
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec

PublicKey pk = KeyFactory
  .getInstance("RSA")
  .generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent))
```